# "MathJax help" link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, hyperlinks, mathjax

When the user is asking or editing a question, a "MathJax help" link is present on the right-hand side of the screen. The link is to http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

Currently, this only leads to a "Page Not Found" screen.

There are Wayback Machine archived copies of the page, for example https://web.archive.org/web/20190118085736/http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/ - perhaps the link could be updated to point to that?

Thanks,

Astrid.

Comment: If this shows up on multiple sites, then it might be a good idea to post in the "[main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)" site.

Comment: I'd better check the other sites - that hadn't occurred to me. Thanks for that - if it is a SE-wide problem instead of Astronomy.SE-specific, then I have indeed posted this in the wrong place.

Comment: @uhoh It is indeed site-wide - fortunately someone else posted on the main meta, and the link now points to http://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/ - I've asked if the SE staff member who fixed it would like to post an answer here so I can accept it.

Comment: Great! If you like, you can simply repost that information as an answer (include the link to the question in meta) and accept it as well, this will help future readers see quickly that it's been addressed (especially those that don't read comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted [over yonder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341346/can-we-get-the-mathjax-reference-link-fixed/341348#341348), this has been fixed now.

Thanks for the report, and please join me in thanking rene for digging up the archived page!